# Doctrine ORM: possible to use EXPLAIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, orm, doctrine

Is it possible to use the EXPLAIN sql command with Doctrine? If not, how do I test/optimize sql code using Doctrine?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't said which version you are using so I can't answer specifically but here are some links:

[Doctrine - How to print out the real sql, not just the prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095394/doctrine-how-to-print-out-the-real-sql-not-just-the-prepared-statment)

[Doctrine - how to get the SQL INSERT query, in the postSave() event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395569/doctrine-how-to-get-the-sql-insert-query-in-the-postsave-event)

[How to debug MySQL/Doctrine2 Queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570608/how-to-debug-mysql-doctrine2-queries)

http://www.chrisshennan.com/2009/12/07/raw-sql-from-doctrine-query-object-revised/#.T7ARLOs6E0E

(Your answer is in one of the above links, if not, please comment)